# PHP FOR & WHILE

Tags: php

creo un array donde tiene años (2012,2013..) y al querer sacar los elementos de la tabla no me arroja nada este es el codigo que uso

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS FROM EDORESULTADO WHERE ANO='".$array[$i]."'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $array=array();
    $index=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){    
        echo '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$row['VENTAS'].'</td>';

    }
}
```

y lo mas curioso es que si quito el array si funciona

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS FROM EDORESULTADO WHERE ANO='2012'";
```

Comment: podrias ver la estructura de $array, mediante var_dump($array), primero hay que saber si de verdad estas accediendo a los valores de años

Comment: ya lo hice si puedo acceder al array de hecho imprimo la variable y la sentencia es correcta si imprime 
SELECT SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS FROM EDORESULTADO WHERE ANO='2012';  pero no se al ejecutar no lo hace la sentencia

Comment: Podrias postear lo que te arroja acceder a tu $array completo? Eso enriquecera tu publicacion

Comment: echo var_dump($arra); este es con el dump 
array(7) { [0]=> string(9) "2012" [1]=> string(9) "2013" [2]=> string(9) "2014" [3]=> string(9) "2015" [4]=> string(9) "2016" [5]=> string(9) "2017" [6]=> string(9) "2018" }

Comment: este es con un print_r  Array ( [0] => 2012 [1] => 2013 [2] => 2014 [3] => 2015 [4] => 2016 [5] => 2017 [6] => 2018 )

Comment: He estado viendo, pero acaso tu intencion en esta linea :  $array=array(); es borrar todo el contenido del arreglo? Si es asi, no habra segunda vez para que  ejecutes el for. Por otro lado, para encontrar ciertos bugs en queries, puedes imprimir tambien la cadena sql que le mandas tal cual.

Comment: Si tu array se llama `$array`  **realmente** (¿no se llamará `$arra`?), puedes hacerlo así: `foreach($array as $v){
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS FROM EDORESULTADO WHERE ANO=$v";  // ... resto del código }`  Si la columna `ANO` es `VARCHAR` entonces pones las comillas simples: `$sql = "SELECT SUM(VENTAS) VENTAS FROM EDORESULTADO WHERE ANO='$v`";`.  De todos modos, tu código es **no óptimo** (no es buena práctica ejecutar consultas en bucles), y además es inseguro (deberías usar consultas preparadas). Pero esas son dos cuestiones aparte.

Comment: muchisimas gracias a los dos por tomarse el tiempo, A. Cedano lo acabo de hacer con el foreach tampoco funciona lo mas raro es que si entro al array pero no ejecuta, o lo ejecuta pero no entrega datos
Sonia Toledo ,el   $array=array();  ya lo quite pero aun así sigue sin arrojar datos

Comment: lo cambie de nombre el array ya que pensé que posiblemente lo estudiase tomando como una palabra reservada pero pues no y sigue sin entregar datos

Comment: es raro que tu var_dump muestre string(9) para el valor 2012 y el resto .. debería ser a lo más string(4) , solucionaste el problema? agrega a la pregunta el codigo que usas para generar el $array

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a suponer que este es tu array (por favor verifica que los nombres de variable sean correctos);

```
$array=array(2012,2013,2014,2015);
```

Puedes sacar los valores del array separados por coma con `implode`:

```
$sqlParams=implode(",",$array);
```

Y modificar la consulta, usando `IN`. De ese modo te evitas enviar una consulta por cada elemento (lo cual afectaría el rendimiento). El código va así tal cual, sin necesidad del antiguo bucle `for` o `foreach`:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS FROM EDORESULTADO WHERE ANO IN($sqlParams)";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){    
    echo '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$row['VENTAS'].'</td>';

}
```

Si en tu base de datos la columna `ANO` no es numérica, puedes crear los parámetros `IN` rodeados de comillas simples del siguiente modo:

```
$sqlParams = "'" . implode ( "', '", $array ) . "'";
```

Aquí la consulta sería así:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS 
FROM EDORESULTADO 
WHERE ANO IN('2012', '2013', '2014', '2015');
```

Si por el contrario, `ANO` es del tipo `INT`, lo dejas como está al principio. La consulta que se va a producir se parecerá a esto:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS 
FROM EDORESULTADO 
WHERE ANO IN(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015);
```

> **Nota sobre la seguridad:** Tu código puede ser altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Cuando se manejan datos que proviene de
>   otras fuentes conviene el uso de consultas preparadas.

Comment: muchas gracias A.Cedano 
lo que necesito es sacar la suma de cada año separado pero pueden variar los año es por eso que saco primero los año y los agrego a un array despues hacer el for o el foreach para que la sentencia cambie los años  y asi sacarlos por cada año

Comment: @ANDRESPALMAHERNANDEZ realmente no entendí bien lo que quieres en realidad ¿podrías explicarlo mejor en la pregunta, poniendo un ejemplo? Si es como dices entonces lo que (parece) que habría que hacer es agrupar por años... sería algo totalmente distinto entonces. Intenta esto y me cuentas: **`SELECT SUM(`VENTAS`) VENTAS FROM EDORESULTADO WHERE ANO IN($sqlParams) GROUP BY ANO`**