# Hacer un WHERE en un SELECT sobre un ARRAY

Tags: php, array

Necesito hacer un *select* en el cual el *WHERE* se realiza sobre un *ARRAY*.

*$id_N3* es el *ARRAY*.

Estoy utilizando este código

```html
$id_N3 = $_POST['id_N3'];

$result = "SELECT * FROM temas_n3 WHERE id = $id_N3";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $result);
//var_dump($res);

if ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $id = $r['id'];
    $cod_N3 = $r['codigo'];
}
```

Pero me da estos errores:

> Notice: Array to string conversion
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Comment: que hay en ese array?

Comment: Como bien comenta @gbianchi, deberías decirnos lo que hay en el array. Si es una lista de valores, puedes usar `WHERE IN()`, combinado con `implode()` para meter la lista de valores en el `IN()`. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/198705/29967), se explica cómo construir la lista, tanto si son valores numéricos como cadenas.

Comment: El array tiene los id de una tabla